# How to encrypt the MySQL backup file in community edition as it doesn't support built-in encryption?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I am using MySQL community edition, which is free, to store my data but it doesn't support the encryption for database backup file. So, how can i manage to encrypt my backup file without the builtin encryption support?

Comment: well - then just encrypt the backup files.. e.g. using openssl

Comment: If you add an answer, i could select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply encrypt the backup files by any 3rd party tool.

OpenSSL is generally available on all platforms. You mahe have a look at [openssl encryption commands](https://www.shellhacks.com/encrypt-decrypt-file-password-openssl/)